# fullcalendar is not a function while using in Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel-5, fullcalendar

I am trying to use fullcalendar in my laravel app.

**Scripts** in webpage source code

```
    <script src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/vendors/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/vendors/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/vendors/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Code in **script.js**

```
$(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: true,
    });
});
```

I have #calendar div in my page and my console is showing error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (script.js:2)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
    at c (jquery.min.js:2)
(anonymous) @ script.js:2
l @ jquery.min.js:2
c @ jquery.min.js:2
setTimeout (async)
w.readyException @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2
l @ jquery.min.js:2
c @ jquery.min.js:2
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2
u @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
fire @ jquery.min.js:2
u @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
c @ jquery.min.js:2
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2
u @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
fire @ jquery.min.js:2
u @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
ready @ jquery.min.js:2
_ @ jquery.min.js:2
```

**My blade file**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Menu</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <ul class="nav flex-column">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('calendar') }}">Calendar</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>

                <div class="card-body full-calendar">
                    <div id='calendar'></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As @Leo suggested, I tried using `https` URLs for resources I am using and also used `ngrok` to create `https` in `localhost`, but still I got same error.

Comment: I will try to see if I find other solutions, while I delete the answer before giving wrong information.

Comment: @Leo I don't think you need to delete your answer, may be that will be solution to some people.

Comment: does the network-tab actually show that all the js are successfully loaded ?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu did you simply try to move the scripts in the 'head' tag?

Comment: @birdspider I found the actual issue.

Comment: @Leo you are correct laravel  app.js is creating the problem.

Comment: yeee, finally :D

Comment: @Leo yes, you are correct. what I did was copying the basic html and tried on the laravel page and got the idea. :D

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Union is strength ;)

Comment: @Leo Always. :)

Comment: @Leo check I have just updated my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the issue is Laravels app.js, that is creating the error, I will add a proper solution to it.

If you will use `npm` and `webpack` and manage dependencies you will not get this error. With out using a dependency manager.

Another solution will be using defer,

You can use defer attribute on all other scripts and the error is gone.

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/vendors/moment.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/vendors/fullcalendar.min.js') }}" defer></script>-->
<script src="{{ asset('js/script.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Comment: It's unlikely that Laravel native code has mistakes.

Comment: @GiamPy, I don't think so, it is about maintaining dependencies.